# Checking cluster of ELB and several EC2 is working

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've made a Ruby script that open #num of EC2 instances opening Apache server on them 
that Attaching them to an ELB instance ,

```
mylb = AWS::ELB.client.new.create_load_balancer(options{})
mylb.register_instances_with_load_balancer(...)
```

now my task is to check that the cluster is working

by I've did is to check is

```
require 'socket'

def domain_exists?(domain)
  begin
    Socket.gethostbyname(domain)
  rescue SocketError
    return false
  end

  true
end
```

but maybe this is not enough 
I read about checking health (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/ELB/Client.html#configure_health_check-instance_method) but I dont really sure about hoe to use it 
but else should I you Test to be 100% positive that my setup is alive and kicking ?